# LinQ to Entities: Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to translate this

```
var db = new PracticeEntities();
var destinations = db.DestinationDetails.
          Where(dd => dd.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
          dd.Destination.Client.Any(c => c.Email == "abc@yahoo.com"));
```

To something like:

```
var destinations =
    from destinations in db.DestinationDetails
       where detail.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
             dd.Destination.Client.Any(db.Client
```

But, I don't know how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var destinations = from dd in db.DestinationDetails
                   where dd.Language.Lang == "en-US" &&
                         dd.Destination.Client.Any(c => c.Email == "abc@yahoo.com");
```

The variable name `dd` after `from` takes the place of the parameter declarations in the lambdas in your original version.